# porque da error en los permisos

Tags: mvc, xml, csv, odoo

Estyo asignanando permisos a los modelos que tengo en un modulo de odoo pero no se si este mal o que haya pasado pero me marca que hay un record extra y reviso el codigo y no encunetro nada

Adjunto codiogo xml:

```
´´´<odoo>

<record id="module_category_mti_picking" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">MTI Recoleccion</field>
    <field name="sequence">4</field>
</record>

<record id="module_category_mti_picking_picking" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">Recoleccion</field>
    <field name="sequence">4</field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="module_category_mti_picking" />
</record>

<record id="group_mti_picking_usuario" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Usuario:Solo puede ver sus propias recolecciones</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_mti_picking_picking" />
</record>

<record id="group_mti_picking_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Administrador:</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_mti_picking_picking" />
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_picking_usuario'))]" />
</record>

<record id="group_inventory_stock_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Administrador Recolección</field>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4,ref('base.user_admin'))]" />
</record>
 <record id="mti_picking_propios_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Recolecciones Propias</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_picking" />
    <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid', '=', user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_picking_usuario'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="mti_picking_todos_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Recolecciones Todos</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_picking" />
    <field name="domain_force"> [(1,'=',1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_picking_manager'))]" />        
</record>
<record id="mti_picking_download_config_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Recoleccion por compania Configuration multi-company</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_picking"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|', ('company_para_id', '=', False), 
     ('company_para_id', 'child_of', [user.company_id.id])]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_picking_usuario'))]"/>
</record>
<record id="module_category_mti_carta_porte" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">MTI Carta Porte</field>
    <field name="sequence">3</field>
</record>

<record id="module_category_mti_carta_porte_cp" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">Carta Porte</field>
    <field name="sequence">1</field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="module_category_mti_carta_porte" />
</record>

<record id="group_mti_carta_porte_usuario" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Usuario: Solo puede ver sus propias cp</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_mti_carta_porte_cp" />
</record>

<record id="group_mti_carta_porte_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Administrador</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_mti_carta_porte_cp" />
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_carta_porte_usuario'))]" />
</record>

<record id="mti_carta_porte_propios_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Carta Porte Propios</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_carta_porte" />
    <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid', '=', user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_carta_porte_usuario'))]" />
</record>

<record id="mti_carta_porte_todos_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Carta Porte Todos</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_carta_porte" />
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_mti_carta_porte_manager'))]" />
</record>

 <record id="module_category_mti_bascula" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">MTI Bascula</field>
    <field name="sequence">5</field>
</record>

 <record id="module_category_mti_bascula" model="ir.module.category">
    <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="sequence">5</field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="module_category_mti_bascula" />
</record>

<record id="mti_bascula_propios_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_bascula"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('create_uid','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(5, ref('group_mti_bascula_usuario'))]"/>
</record>
<record id="mti_bascula_todos_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mti_bascula"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
    <fiel name="groups" eval="[(5, ref('group_mti_bascula_manager'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="group_mti_bascula_usuario" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Usuario: Solo puede ver sus propopios reportes de 
  bascula</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_mti_bascula" />
</record>

<record id="group_mti_bascula_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Administrador</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_mti_bascula" />
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(5, ref('group_mti_bascula_usuario'))]" />
</record>
```

esos son todos los permisos que tengo en el xml y de ahi es donde me manda el error no se si hice algo mal o me falto agregar algo porque los ultimos permisos de bascual fueron los que agregue pero manda error en el primer permiso que podria hacer eb este caso para poder corregir el error que manda en la terminal

Ajunto imagen de la terminal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

marca que hay un record extra

Comment: Vuelves a tener algunos campos `field` con la barra diagonal...

Comment: los volvi a poner de forma normal pense que seria como la vez pasada y no

Comment: Tienes dos iguales: `<record id="module_category_mti_bascula" model="ir.module.category">`

Comment: si porque el otro hace referencia a la categoria del modelo y el primero solo es la secuencia

Comment: Pero solo puede haber un `id` con el mismo nombre, no dos, es una característica única...

Comment: En el cóedigo que pones no estas cerrando la etiqueta `odoo`

Comment: pude arreglarlo peeo me anda un error en el archivo csv

Comment: Bueno, si has arreglado lo que te comenté, es mejor que hagas otra pregunta diferente con lo del `csv`, añadiendo el código, etc.

Comment: vale muchas gracias